# How to read a byte back in Java?

Tags: java, string, byte

I need to read in bytes from a file, turn them into a string, do something with the string, then get the bytes back from the string, so I have the following code :

```
byte[] bFile=readFileBytes(filePath);
StringBuilder massageBuilder=new StringBuilder();

for (int i=0;i<bFile.length;i++) massageBuilder.append(bFile[i]);

String x=massageBuilder.charAt(n)+"";

...

byte b=x.getBytes();
```

But the last step doesn't get back the byte, what's wrong, I wan to get back the "massageBuilder.charAt(n)" ?

Comment: Then, what's the error? Can the value of `.charAt(n)` be used?

Comment: Please check your code sample, as it can't compile, e.g. `byte b=x.getBytes();` most probably should read `byte[] b=x.getBytes();` After that, please clarify your problem, e.g. with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get back to the original bytes given how you're adding them to your string builder.

Take this example:

```
byte[] bFile = "This is the input string".getBytes();
StringBuilder massageBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++)
    massageBuilder.append(bFile[i]);
```

When you print `massageBuilder`, you get

```
8410410511532105115321161041013210511011211711632115116114105110103
```

These become a random sequence of numbers that offers no way of distinguishing original bytes. One or more characters in the resulting string will be linked to a single input `byte`. Even if you knew the character set of the original text, you'd still have trouble because of ambiguous sequences.

It might be possible if you used a delimiter of some sort...

```
massageBuilder.append(bFile[i]).append("-");
//84~104~105~115~32~105~115~32~116~104~101~32~105~110~112~117~116~...
```

In which case you can split by it and rebuild your byte array.

Comment: Great insight, so [1] can you show me some sample code of your suggestion ? [2] According to my original approach, can I just get the first half to recover the byte ? (without using a delimiter ?)

Comment: If you use a delimiter, it's as simple as `String[] bytes = massageBuilder.toString().split("~"); byt[] rebuilt = new byte[bytes.length]; for(int i =0; i < bytes.length; i++) rebuilt[i] = Byte.parseByte(bytes[i]);`. Not sure what you mean by first half, the problem is that when you see, say, '84' in the string, you don't know whether to make two or a single byte (either could be valid)

Comment: Excellent, this is the one I'm looking for, thanks !